# DocumentPaginator: only half grid is printed

Tags: wpf, printing

Some years ago I found some example code to pretty print the content of a listview, repeating in each page a document header, footer, and table header.

Basically there is a class that implements **DocumentPaginator** and calculates the number of rows that fit in the page

Here is the code to launch the print:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
printDialog.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
Size pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, 
printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
DocumentPaginator paginator = new SimpleListDocumentPaginator(param as ListView, 
documentTitle, pageSize, new Thickness(30, 20, 60, 20));
printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Somename");
```

Here is the code in GetPage(int pageNumber) which adjust the grid dimension:

```
double width = this.PageSize.Width - (this.PageMargin.Left + this.PageMargin.Right);
double height = this.PageSize.Height - (this.PageMargin.Top + this.PageMargin.Bottom);
pageGrid.Measure(new Size(width, height));
pageGrid.Arrange(new Rect(this.PageMargin.Left, this.PageMargin.Top, width, height));
return new DocumentPage(pageGrid);
```

**pageGrid** is a grid created from the Listview, with same columns

In the past year with a different OS and a different .net framework it worked correctly, now the table is cut on the right at about 60% of the total width.

Page orientation is set to landscape and calculation are done with landscape values, but during printing it seems the document is considered 'Portrait' and cut at the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The code for printing comes from an old project on **Codeproject**, [Custom Data Grid Document Paginator](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138233/Custom-Data-Grid-Document-Paginator).

As stated above I'm sure it worked well in the past changing the page orientation to Landscape, now it cuts the table at the page Portrait width.

**DocumentPage** has 2 constructors:

```
public DocumentPage (System.Windows.Media.Visual visual);
public DocumentPage (System.Windows.Media.Visual visual, System.Windows.Size pageSize, System.Windows.Rect bleedBox, System.Windows.Rect contentBox);
```

Using the second one and passing the correct pageSize it works correctly. The  original source code uses the first one, the **visual** is *measured and arranged* to Landscape dimension, but DocumentPage uses Portrait dimensions. This is not the same behavior of 10 years ago, don't know when this change happened.